# When reviewing first posts, is it a good idea to upvote acceptable questions, to give the user access to some of the earlier privlidges?

Tags: discussion, review, new-users, up-votes

One of the painful parts of being a new user, is that you can't comment for example, or use downvotes.

For this reason, I think it's a good idea to give new users some easy upvotes to get them over this threshold.

The suggestion is, when a question is of acceptable quality, but not question you would otherwise upvote, it should be upvoted. (I will be upvoting it, anyway).

Comment: I’d recommend that you vote solely on a question’s merit, and not on the user. If everyone did that, we would have fewer problems.

Comment: @minitech Except for when you have new users posting comments as answers because they can't make comments, etc.

Comment: In which case, *they shouldn't be posting at all*.  If a user understands what they're posting is not acceptable, but does it anyway, is that really someone we want around?

Comment: @user1068446 **Especially** then. If a new user starts by breaking the rules, why should we reward them for that?

Comment: "I will be upvoting it, anyway" - attaboy! "I don't care that it makes the site worse. I don't care that it's against the spririt of the site's rules. I will just do whatever I want to!"

Comment: Wow this must be the most negative voted question I've seen. Is there a badge for it?

Answer (score 13):

> The suggestion is, when a question is of acceptable quality, but not question you would otherwise upvote, it should be upvoted. (I will be upvoting it, anyway).

No, only upvote it if you would otherwise upvote it. If it's of acceptable quality, it's fairly likely to be upvoted anyway (depending on the SE site), so there's not much of an issue here.

Privileges are *earned* through good participation. Don't favour new users just because they're new, or try to get them over those "painful parts". They won't be in those painful parts long, unless they don't contribute much worthwhile, and then they're not the kind of person we should be interested in extending those privileges to.

If we wanted to get new users over those basic privileges ASAP, we might as well just lower the rep threshold for them to 5 rather than systemically using upvoting incorrectly.